# Simple JS Slider - rotation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, slider

I am trying to make a simple js slide. I did something but when I click the button  next image just blinking but doesnt stay. Here is my code:

```
var imgArr = new Array();
imgArr=["b1.jpg","b2.jpg","b3.jpg"];
var index = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var Image = document.getElementById("img");
    index++;
    Image.src = imgArr[index];
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a complete example to make it easier for others to help you. You can create a snippet on a site like jsfiddle.com or codepen.io

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you're letting the index go over

```js
var imgArr = new Array();

imgArr[0] = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/696818834683142145/3SARjDxT.jpg";

imgArr[1] = "http://www.jabaixei.com.br/images/imagens_das_postagens/photoscape_logo_black.png";

imgArr[2] = "http://icon-icons.com/icons2/12/PNG/256/images_nikon_camera_1745.png";

var index = 0;

function myFunction() {
  var Image = document.getElementById("img");
  Image.src = imgArr[index];
  index++;
  if (index == 3) index = 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="" " style="width:100px; "/>
<button id="btnChange " onclick="myFunction(); ">change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent your counter from going higher than the highest index in the array. Also, we can reduce your code quite a bit.

```js
// We can declare and fill the array in one statement:
var imgArr = ["http://www.greatgrubclub.com/domains/greatgrubclub.com/local/media/images/medium/4_1_1_apple.jpg", 
              "http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4bcb7941-ba24-495e-8bc1-6145e8bf1bb5/1be9da1e-92d6-471d-801a-09168c01a5ac.jpg", 
              "http://images.wisegeek.com/red-and-green-barlett-pears.jpg"];
              
var index = 0;              

// Just scan the document for the image element once,
// not every time the function runs
var img =  document.getElementById("img");
var btn =  document.getElementById("btn");

// You have to set up the click of the button to invoke your function
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
 img.src= imgArr[index];

 // If the counter is less than one less than the array length, increment it
 // Otherwise, reset it to zero.
 if (index < imgArr.length - 1){
   index++;
 } else {
   index = 0;
 }
}
```

```css
img { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Next</button><img id="img">
```